# Choosing framework type for selenium RC/Webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, test-automation-framework

I had opportunity to work in around 3 different projects, where selenium have been used extensively. Among them 2 were based on Data driven (say test cases driven by testng XML for each scenario with different data) frame work and one keyword driven. And I find that the Keyword driven framework is more successful based on how much extensively it was used and the coverage it had in the project. It was mainly because of the 'easy of use' it provided to the manual testers who also practiced writing test cases with the key word driven functionality of the framework, and required only one  or two automation testers who had enough coding knowledge to implement new functionalists to the framework when a new addition to AUT came.

From your experience please explain which would be a better type of framework based on test coverage it can provide to an application, re usability, ease of use and maintainability? (I believe these are the factors that brings in good ROI for an automation project.

Comment: @Tarun I didn get your question

Comment: this may help in understanding if you don't get answer of your most valid questions - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34919/is-a-51-acceptance-rate-too-low

Comment: Thanks Tarun, I never bothered about those points. I will try to make required chnages.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to choose between a keyword framework and data driven.  The keywords can include creating data either internally or from a source.  I'm using Robot Framework to drive my tests, where I create keywords which randomize data.

Comment: thanks for that point. By keyword(KW) or data driven(DD) frame, I meant the option(or interface) that the end user of the test frame work would use to create individual test cases with the already created AUT specific navigation functions, user event API's or functions, page objects or whatever.

Comment: Normally the UI of a test automation frame work would be an xls sheet in which we give row by row inputs of test step key words if KW framework and in the basis of each row in an xls as a single test case and the test steps would be in respect to the specific columns in a row where we give input data for DD frame.      Hope I made my point more clear. I would like to know based on that perspective the usability and acceptance of a frame work